# Recover files on a Windows 7 host from a user who has been deleted from active directory?

Tags: active-directory, files, users

Is there a way to recover data (Files, Programs, etc...) on a Windows 7 machine assigned to a specific Active directory user, that has since been deleted from Active Directory? For some reason the previous IT Manager deleted the user without archiving any data from the machine before hand and my higher ups are asking if I can retrieve said data.

Answer (score 2):

Log onto the computer. Find the user profile for the user. Copy the data to where ever you need.

Comment: I looked in C:\users\<username> already. There was no information there. The Documents file that is hosted on our server was empty as well. So either she didn't use the shared folder for storage purposes or the information just seems to be gone...